# Invalid JSON Post Payload in Post Man

Tags: json, http, postman

Why is this not a valid `raw JSON (application/json)` POST payload in Post Man?

```
{
    [
        {
            "keyOne": "valueOne",
            "keyTwo": "valueTwo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer braces indicate it is an object, but the outer object has no key. It should look more like:

```
{
    "array_name": [ {
        "keyOne": "valueOne",
        "keyTwo": "valueTwo"
    }]
}
```

OR, if you want an array, you don't need the outer braces:

```
[{
    "keyOne": "valueOne",
    "keyTwo": "valueTwo"
}]
```

Comment: This was it! Awesome! Concise. Calculated.